# Проблема с тегом descriptorRefs, idea не видит его

Tags: java, maven, jar

[image: descriptorRefs]   Хотел разобраться с созданием и запуском jar файлов. Собрал в кучу что нашел что нужно в pom по этому, но уже в idea получил вот такую проблемку - тег descriptorRefs idea попросту не видит. Почему именно этот тег не виден?

Если кто подскажет, буду ооочень благодарен!!!

Comment: вы включили автоподгрузку зависимостей?

Comment: @michael В настройках галочка не стояла - поставил, но ничего не изменилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать assembly плагин (добавить его plugins что в build секции)

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        <mainClass>test.Test</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! помогло!

Comment: @Besuch Рад помочь )